# Getting details of a DLL in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, file, dll, properties

Is there a way to get the values of various properties of (both .NET and non-.NET) DLLs in .NET?

I'd like to read the 'Product name' field in particular.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Utilize [FileVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.aspx)...you can get [quite a bit of info from this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo_members.aspx)

```
using System.Diagnostics;

FileVersionInfo myFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("C:\\temp\\Test.dll");
MessageBox.Show(myFileVersionInfo.ProductName.ToString()); //here it is
```